# Logging in using JSON to Reddit API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, reddit, httparty

I've been trying to build a little bot which will be using Reddit's API. I can break down and read all the info I'm receiving without problem, but I haven't been able to send anything yet.

**What I want to do is:**
Send a prepared JSON string to http://www.reddit.com/api/login and get some kind of response if I succeeded or failed.

If you need more info about Reddit's API: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API

**This is what I have so far:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

class Login
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'reddit.com/'
  default_params :output => 'json'
  format :json
  def post(message)
    options = {:body => JSON.generate(message)}
    self.class.post('api/login', options)
  end
end

login = Login.new()
pp login.post({'username' => 'USERNAME', 'passwd' => 'PW'})
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1060:in `request': undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Even though a very similar chunk of code would post to Twitter. Also, I'm not sure if my code actually gets some kind of response from the site or not.

*To me it doesn't matter if I use HTTParty or not, so if you know a much better way of doing this, feel free to share!*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this

```
class Login
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://www.reddit.com'

  def post(username, password)
    options = {:body => {:user => username, :passwd => password, :api_type => 'json'}}
    self.class.post("/api/login/#{username}", options)
  end
end

Login.new.post('user', 'pass')
```

Just remember that API url for a login must be: `http://www.reddit.com/api/login/USERNAME` (with www) and you should pass `api_type` param in request.